# history.js's replaceState() keeps appending new hashes to url

Tags: jquery, history.js

i'm using safari 5.1.5 on a mac

my current url is: www.mysite.com

then i click a specific group:

```
History.replaceState(null, null, 'groups/' + group_id + '/');
```

if i click group 32, i get the url:
www.mysite.com/groups/32/

fine so far... but if i click group 31 after that, i get:
www.mysite.com/groups/32/groups/31/

...or better yet, if i go to the first group then, i get:
www.mysite.com/groups/32/groups/31/groups/32/

... and so on...

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start your URL with a `/`, it will be expressed relative to document root:

```
replaceState(null, null, '/groups/' + group_id + '/');
```

Omit the `/`, and the assumption is that you're looking for a relative URL.

Comment: I had this problem as well, I am the dumb.