# history.pushState appends slugs to url on second click AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

so I got ajax filter for filtering out terms in custom taxonomy. It update url fine on first click but on second it appends data to already existing url for the first taxonomy I clicked.

So first time I click URL updated to: http://localhost:3000/acquisitions/content/

Second time I click on different taxonomy in the sidebar it looks like this: http://localhost:3000/acquisitions/content/conversions/copywriting/

How can I prevent this from happening? So what I want is for URL to remove slugs from category that's first being clicked and populate it with one that's clicked after not append it.

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item', function(event){
            (event).preventDefault();
            
            var category = $(this).data('category');
            var taxonomy = $(this).data('posttype');
            var categorySlug = $(this).data('slug');

            $.ajax({
                url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
                data: { 
                    action: 'filterterm', 
                    category: category, 
                    taxonomy:  $(this).data('taxonomy'),
                    posttype:  $(this).data('posttype')
                    },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result){
                    $('#response').html(result);
                    // changing URL based on the category slug
                    window.history.pushState(null, null, taxonomy + 's/' + categorySlug + '/');
                },
                error: function(result){
                    console.warn(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418332/history-jss-replacestate-keeps-appending-new-hashes-to-url